# C# html decode before export to excel

Tags: c#, excel, encoding

I have a problem with some text going around my app, thing is after user add a text with formatting, I save that type of formatting (HTML) in my database, for later use. So once i show it back to the user I can still keep the format

Example of text :

```
bla<br>bla<br>bla bla<br>
```

And for showing on my controls, that works, I am using:

```
Context.Server.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
Context.Server.HtmlEncode(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
```

But problem shows up, when I want that same text to export to Excel file ...

```
foreach (DataRow row in dr)
{
   for (col = 0; col < dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count; col++)
   {
      rowData[rowCnt, col] = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(row[col].ToString());
   }
   rowCnt++;
}

oSheet.get_Range("A2", lastColumn + (rowCnt + 1).ToString()).Value2 = rowData;
```

And once I open excel file ... that text shows up like this

```
bla&lt;br&gt;bla&lt;br&gt;bla bla&lt;br&gt;
```

Does anyone know some way to export this text to excel file, but to keep formatting of text?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried not encoding it?

Comment: Yes I did, I store it in DB as nvarchar, it shows up as 'bla<br>bla<br>bla bla<br>'

Comment: I mean, when you export to save it to Excel, have you tried just `rowData[rowCnt, col] = row[col].ToString();`

Comment: Yep, i understood your question, i tried that and get same thing

Comment: So it's showing < and > in Excel as `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but you want it to actually show `<` and `>`? Probably not the best solution, but you could replace the string like `string rowDataOutput = Replace(row[col], "&lt;", "<")` and do the same for `&gt;`

Comment: Sorry, wrote that wrong. Check my answer below.

Comment: Are you asking how to _strip HTML_ instead of what you're asking? If so see answer about using HTML Agility Pack...

Comment: I'm actually not sure what he's asking. I just re-read his last sentence, and it sounds like he wants HTML formatting in his Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I want C# to see <br> as new line and export it as new line in Excel, so i would have formated text in excel  ... I don't want to see HTML tags in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the best solution, but you could replace the string text:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dr)
{
   for (col = 0; col < dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count; col++)
   {
      string outputData = row[col].ToString().Replace("&lt;", "<");
      outputData = outputData.Replace("&gt;", ">");
      rowData[rowCnt, col] = outputData;
   }
   rowCnt++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, I will test this fix a bit more and let you know how did it work

Answer (score 0):

Install [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Then you can create a method like this to get the text value.

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml("bla<br>bla<br>bla bla<br>");
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var descendant in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
    {
        buffer.Append(descendant.InnerHtml);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks for help man ... but i failed hard at including HTML pack to my project, ill figure something out. Thanks anyway

Comment: What did you mean by "you failed to include the agility pack"? In package manager console run this command. `Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack`

Comment: I mean I never done it ... i tried including it as a .NET reference, but ill google about it a bit more and figure it out